# How to get data from SQL for autocomplete with JQuery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, sql

i have a CustomerTable with the area of CustomerName.How can i show autocomplete when i write something in the textbox(txtCustomerName) to add a new Customer object in an aspx page ?

Comment: access a web service with ajax?

Comment: Im a student and we havent studied WebServices,so my prof doesnt let us to use WebServices.I have to do it with JQuery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using ASP.NET webforms, combining a [Page Method + jQuery ajax approach](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/) with [jQuery UI Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) would probably be the simplest way to have something that gets the data on demand.

Answer (score 1):

Note sure if you use Asp.NET WebForms or MVC. But you can do this using jQuery `ajax` and the jQuery autocomplete plugin.

**I would like to provide a sample but for that we need more information and source code.**

Check out this [TextBox AutoComplete with ASP.NET and jQuery UI](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=515)

and [jQuery Autocomplete plugin](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/)

Comment: im gonna try the first one.Thank you.Im gonna let you know if it works or not.

Comment: in your answer,if im not wrong,i have to use webservices.I shouldnt use webservice,my prof doesnt let me do with it,also i havent studied Web Services.He showed me one that is working with jquery,but not all code.I can read data from sql but i couldnt assign it to the autocomplete's source

Comment: This is not really a Webservice.

Answer (score -1):

This is one of the solutions: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/